# Does CLGeocoder() geocode zip codes outside of the US?

Tags: swift, core-location

I am using CoreLocation geocoder to geocode zip codes and find their corresponding city and states. When I run a zip code such as 75001 which represents a city in Texas but also a region in Paris (Europe), the geocoder matches it to the city in Texas. But I would like my app to support users in Europe as well. I was wondering if the geocoder biases how to geocode the zip code based on the location of the request. So if I was in Europe now would this same geocode for 75001 be matched to Paris? Or would it still match to Texas? I would appreciate anyone's knowledge on this. I have already read the documentation on CLGeocoder and was not able to find something referring to this.

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(zipCode) { (placemarks, _ ) in

}
```

Comment: How about including the name of the country in the string?

Comment: Btw, `CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString("75001")` gave me a `geocodeFoundNoResult` error. What is the value of `zipCode`?

Comment: @Sweeper hello, sorry 75001 was a bad example. I tested "10178" for geocoding and it matches it to New York New York. But this zip Code is also for Berlin. When I try "10178 Germany" this matches it correctly to Berlin. So basically does apples Geocoder bias the United States? Would it not automatically adapt to the users country?

Comment: @Sweeper adding in the Country will work but sometimes users have their location disabled. Do you see a possible work around. thanks again.

Comment: I would say the responsibility is on the user to enable location services so that they can get an accurate geocoding result from you. :)

Comment: @Sweeper :) Ik man but a bunch of users think they're being tracked down if they turn on location services. Do you have any knowledge as to if the geocoder will auto adapt to the users country?

Answer (score -1):

Geocoder takes into account the users location if possible to spit out the most relevant result. it does not bias the US. But for example if you throw in "Statue of Liberty" it will throw out New York even if there is "State of Liberty restaurant" in Europe. It takes into account the popularity or relevance of the search results. To specify the region "hint" for geocoder to narrow the results down you should use "in region" like "geocoder.geocodeAddressString(zipCode, in: <CLRegion?>) { (placemarks, _ ) in" This is a hint for geocoder to look in that specific region. This was verified by someone from apple.